# How do you change the order of uploaded videos?

Tags: entities

How can we change this page so new content added goes to the top, not the bottom?

http://www.liveops.com/resources/videos

When it's added to this page, it goes to the top:
http://www.liveops.com/resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listed videos are created using a view. It looks like the view is called Resources (or something similiar). Edit that view, and there should be a tab called 'block', where you can edit the block view. In there, under 'sort', choose 'nid' and set it to sort descending.

Comment: It's probable that your videos are not nodes, but rather files. In that case they will not have an nid but rather an fid (file id). While sorting on fid (or nid, if you are creating a node for each video) is valid and should work, you may want to consider sorting by creation date instead.

Comment: Good point, although the videos appear to be embedded Youtube videos, so they won't have a FID in such a case.